# Why addEventListener for form submit doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

Im getting hard to dealing with addEventListener "submit" to form. Here is the script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Hehe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="q" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();" />
            <input type="submit" value="Testing" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(document.readyState);
            window.onload = function(){
                console.log(document.readyState);
                document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                },false);

                var form = document.createElement('form');
                    form.method= "post";
                var input= document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.name = "test";
                    input.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    form.submit();
                    },false);
                form.appendChild(input);
                var input2= document.createElement('input');
                    input2.type = "submit";
                    input2.name = "sbt";
                form.appendChild(input2);
                form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
                    alert("test");
                    e.preventDefault();
                },false);
                document.body.appendChild(form);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST); 
    exit;
}
?>
```

From above script, I have succeded kill form submit event when submit button clicked,  but when I change the submit trigger to other part, such as when textbox clicked, the "submit" event still post directly.
I don't understand why it is happened and how to fix this problem..

Thank you for attention :-) And you r answer will be great for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
input.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    form.submit();
                    },false);
```

You could use:

```
input.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    input2.click();
                    },false);
```

Just make sure to move `var input2= document.createElement('input');` before it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wcpx4/

Comment: Hi niklas, thanks that is work fine. but when we not use submit button, so the trigger is have to directly using form.submit();, I try to make other sample and I think addEventListener cannot bind form.submit() method, but it work when I override form.submit() with form.submit = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, hmm.. its confusing..